# How to generate a Makefile with sources in sub-directories?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have source located in the following manner.

```
/src/main.cpp
/src/hearts/hearts.cpp
/src/spades/spades.cpp
/src/oldmaid/oldmaid.cpp
```

How would I go about creating a makefile for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excerpt from my Makefile. This searches for cpp files in the src directory and compiles them. You can add new files and make picks them automatically.

```
CC = g++  

all: compile
   find src -name '*.o' -print0 | xargs -0 $(CC) -o myExecutable

compile:
    find src -name '*.cpp' -print0 | xargs -0 $(CC) -c

clean:
    find src -iname '*.o' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: This is if you were to have the makefile one directory above src. What would I change to put it in the src directory?

Comment: I only ask because I don't think my main.cpp is actually running once I make all the files

Comment: simple. Just change all the find src something something to find . something something. e.g. find src -name '*.o' to find . -name '*.o'. The first argument to find is the location to find the cpp or .o files.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this would be to add all the source to a variable and use that variable in your make command.  Here's a snippet with the relevant sections.

```
APP_SRC=src/main.cpp \
    src/hearts/hearts.cpp \
    src/spades/spades.cpp \
    src/oldmaid/oldmaid.cpp

CC=g++
CFLAGS= -Wall (and any other flags you need)


#
# Rules for building the application and library 
#
all: 
make bin


bin: 
$(CC)  $(CFLAGS) $(APP_SRC)
```

And here's a [link](http://oreilly.com/catalog/make3/book/) to a good book to get started learning Make.